# xampp taking so long for large query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this php program in a localhost. And I have 2 tables from my database which has a datalmost 13,000 plus each table. I want to check if NameFromA from TableA exist in NameFromB from TableB. I have this different codes working when I try to use small amount of data around 100 data.

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE  NameFromA = NameFromB)

 SELECT a.* FROM TableA AS a, TableB AS b WHERE a.NameFromA = b.NameFromB

 SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON(NameFromA = NameFromB)
```

My problem is when I try running it and comparing the 13,000 plus data nothing happens. It has no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need an index.  In particular:

```
create index idx_tableb_namefromb on tableb(namefromb);
```

This should make all three faster.  However, don't use commas in the `from` clause, so just forget the syntax for the second version.

Note:  the second and third versions could also use an index on `tablea` instead of the above index:

```
create index idx_tablea_namefroma on tablea(namefroma);
```

Which is better depends on the data.

Comment: @mar . . . You create the index once for the table.  Then the database can use the index when it needs to.  You would do it wherever you created the table.

Comment: after creating the index. How should I use it in my query? Should I use my code then?

Comment: Your third query with join is by far the best and fastest. Hane namefromA et B with an index. 13k records is nothing. Should not take more than 2 milisecs.

Comment: Yes but you will need the indexes . Comas are not nescessary